# Dropzone JS not using Config

Tags: javascript, php, configuration, dropzone

im trying to simply config a Dropzone element to my needs.
However, it dosent seem to want to load my config.

Currently i have the latest Dropzone JS installed and loaded.

this is the code im using

```
<form id="omadropzone" action="upload/doupload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
Dropzone.options.omadropzone = {
maxFilesize: 500,
init: function() {
this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
console.log("File progress", progress);
});
}
};
</script>
```

Ive been playing around with this the last 30 minutes trying everything i found on the internet. 
I just cannot seem to figure out whats missing.

There is nothing shown in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got it working with this code under

```
Dropzone.optionsForElement = function (element) {
  // Get the `Dropzone.options.elementId` for this element if it exists
  if (element.getAttribute("id")) {
    return Dropzone.options[camelize(element.getAttribute("id"))];
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

in the Dropzone JS i added

```
Dropzone.options.datenhochlad = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    url: '/test/upload/doupload.php',
    init: function () {
        var myDropzone = this;
        // Update selector to match your button
        $("#hochladdaten").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        this.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
            // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
            var data = $('#datenhochlad').serializeArray();
            $.each(data, function(key, el) {
                formData.append(el.name, el.value);
            });

        });

    }
```